# I want to define a function ‘wordsLength’ that will calculate the length of the words in a given sentence

Tags: haskell

Sample Input – wordsLength “This is Arya”, Sample output – [4,2,4]

I can get the length for a list of string but not for the string itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a quesiton. Please read [ask].

Comment: `wordsLength = map length . words`

Answer (score 6):

This is the function you have:

```
length :: [a] -> Int
```

What you would like to do is write `lengths` which preserves the structure of the input list and applies `length` to each one of its elements.

```
lengths :: [[a]] -> [Int]
```

Now, look at the type of `map`, can you see how to combine `length` and `map` to get `lengths`?

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
length <$> words "This is Arya"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16875848)

Comment: Given that the original poster could not come up with this themselves,  it needs more explanation.

Comment: @Blackbam This does technically give the "right" answer, so I would leave it, rather than delete it. But it could be massively improved as an answer.